# crear contenedor para gráficos dentro de una tabla

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, google-chart-api

Estoy tratando de crear un contenedor para los gráficos desde JavaScript dentro una tabla, pero no lo esta creando dentro de la tabla como quisiera.

Podría usar el .html(''), pero los contenedores que quiero crear para los gráficos, me saldrían como inexistentes.
$("#contenedor").html(mi_tabla);

Quisiera ayuda con eso por favor. Necesito que sea dentro de la tabla, el código siguiente es un ejemplo de lo q tengo.

```
<html>
  <head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart']});
      google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

      function drawChart() {

        var lista = [
            {"area": "AAA", "abiertos": 10, "cerrados": 20},
            {"area": "BBB", "abiertos": 25, "cerrados": 5},
            {"area": "CCC", "abiertos": 15, "cerrados": 15}
        ];
        
        $("#contenedor").append('<table style="border: 2px solid #000000;">');
        
        $.each(lista, function (i, fila) {
            var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
            data.addColumn('string', 'Topping');
            data.addColumn('number', 'Slices');
            
            data.addRows([
                ['Abiertos', fila.abiertos],
                ['Cerrados', fila.cerrados],
            ]);
            var options = {title: fila.area};
            
            $("#contenedor").append('<tr>');
            $("#contenedor").append('<td>');
            $("#contenedor").append('<div id="'+fila.area+'"></div>');//--Contenedor para el grafico
            var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById(fila.area));
            chart.draw(data, options);  
            
            $("#contenedor").append('</td>');
            $("#contenedor").append('</tr>');
        });   

        $("#contenedor").append('</table>');
        
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="contenedor"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Revisando el codigo el .append('')  aparece la etiqueta </table cerrada
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

Estuve probando tu código y te paso imagen de lo que encontré.

No se si esto te sirva:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Revisa estas líneas (Deben de ser las de cierre y están abiertas y mal escaladas):

```
$("#contenedor").append('<tr>');
$("#contenedor").append('<td>');
```

Déjalas así:

```
$("#contenedor").append('</td>');
$("#contenedor").append('</tr>');
```